# jQuery nth-child selector not working

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a div id (auctions), and I want to swap out the HTML with the children of auction-list. However, jQuery cannot select the children of the auction-list div.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="all">      
    <div id="auctions"></div>
</div>

<div id="auction-list" class="hide">
    <div class="auction">Test</div>
    <div class="auction">Test</div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
alert($("#auction-list").children().length);
alert($("#auction-list").html());
alert($("#auction-list:nth-child(1)").html());
alert($("#auction-list:nth-child(2)").html());
$("#auctions").html($("#auction-list:nth-child(1)").html());
```

And here are the outputs for the Javascript alerts:

**First Alert**

```
2
```

**Second Alert**

```
<div class="auction">Test</div>
<div class="auction">Test</div>
```

**Third Alert**

```
null
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a space between your selectors, like this:

```
alert($("#auction-list :nth-child(1)").html());
//                    ^-- Space here
```

With your selector, it's looking for the element `#auction-list`, which is a the 1st child of another element, when what you're actually looking for an element that is the nth child of the list.

Comment: This is it. I needed a space before the colon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be using the `:nth-child` selector on an element id. It should be a classed item

like;

```
alert($("div.auction-item:nth-child(1)").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#auction-list > .auction:nth-child(2)")
```

Take a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). You are trying to select the n-th `#auction-list` element instead of its children.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("#auction-list").children().length);
alert($("#auction-list").html());
alert($("#auction-list div:nth-child(1)").html());
alert($("#auction-list div:nth-child(2)").html());
$("#auctions").html($("#auction-list:nth-child(1)").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the click event would fire fine in IE and chrome but not firefox.  I had overlooked a typo.  Thought I would share in case it helps someone.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".test table tr:nth-child(1n+2").click(function () {
            alert(this.id); 
        });
});
```

I was missing the ) after +2.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xv3bca60/7/